# I can run :terminal in Neovim, but it thinks terminal is missing

Tags: neovim, terminal

I have NVIM v0.4.2 and can run `:terminal`. Despite that, `echo has('terminal')` gives `0`. In addition, if I try to run a command of [vimteractive](https://github.com/williamjameshandley/vimteractive), an error occurs with

```
Your version of vim is not compiled with +terminal. Cannot use vimteractive.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`has('terminal')` is for Vim only. In Neovim this feature is always present, and so checking it is *not* supported.

> :h feature-compile

- Nvim always includes ALL features, in contrast to Vim (which ships with
  various combinations of 100+ optional features). Think of it as a leaner
  version of Vim's "HUGE" build. This reduces surface area for bugs, and
  removes a common source of confusion and friction for users.

Comment: Another question remains. Why does `vimteractive` give an error?

Comment: @T_T Obviously, the plugin has no support for Neovim (Terminal API in Vim and Neovim differs much). And the fact it gives an erroneous text message should be considered as a bug itself.